# Gitblit uses a lot of space to store data

Tags: git, gitblit

I have a Gitblit server (Debian),
Everything going to be ok except i saw the Disk space of Git repo on Gitblit increased very unormally.
When i push a file(only 40Kb) is will increased more 300M in Gitblit, I have check a lot of time.The same problem.

have somebody faced with this issue ?

Comment: So if you push a single small file, the GITBLIT disk space increases by 300MB each time?

Comment: Yes, the first time i upload the origin Source(282MB) and after some push (i just only changed some comments) i pushed its back again, i checkéd a lot of time and now the data is 1.4GB

Comment: I use Visual studio tool for git to push, i think there is a bug with this extension cause this matter